# In Nativescript, what generates the `platforms/tempPlugin` folder?

Tags: nativescript

I'm currently running into an issue where one of the gradle files in my tempPlugin folder is missing some detail.

If I modify the gradle file, then run `tns run android`, the file gets replaced.  Something within that process is messed up, but what is unimportant.

What I'd like to know is what the `tempPlugin` folder does and how it is generated.

Is it generated by nativescript, or the plugin, or both?  Why does it exist (why not just generate straight to the android and ios folders)?

Comment: It's generated by NativeScript CLI to build the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this code:

https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-cli/blob/master/lib/services/android-plugin-build-service.ts

The gradle template is pulled from here: https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-cli/tree/master/vendor/gradle-plugin (which is installed to your global NPM folder)
the other files a copied / processed in by the code mentioned above.